# special character replace in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace

I want to replace all "[[title]]" in String "[[title]]"

my code is:

```
root@lll:/mnt/f/work/files# a="[[title]]"
root@lll:/mnt/f/work/files# title="1111"
root@lll:/mnt/f/work/files# echo ${a/[[title]]/$title}
```

the output is：

```
[[titl1111]
```

I want is:

```
1111
```

How to do it, and why do I get the wrong answer?

Comment: what is the sense of replacement one single word with another if the defined replacement word `1111` already contain the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `[` as it is a meta character

```
$ a='[[title]]'
$ title='1111'
$ echo "${a/\[\[title]]/$title}"
1111
```

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Ranges and `Pattern Matching` section in `man bash`

Answer (score 0):

The opening square bracket is a special character, so you have to escape it:

```
echo "${a/\[\[title]]/$title}"
```